# How to pass some parameters to the @GET() method on Retrofit Java Interface?

Tags: java, android, json, gson, retrofit

I am making a weather app by using the wunderground API. I am also using Retrofit2 and GSON library.

Here is the API URL format to get the JSON response:

**`http://api.wunderground.com/api/API_KEY/conditions/q/ISO_COUNTRY_CODE/CITY_NAME.json`**

I've declared an java API_Interface as follows:

```
public interface API_Interface {

    @GET("/api/{apikey}/conditions/q/BD/{city}.json")
    Call<CurrentObservation> getCurrentWeather(
            @Path("apikey") String apikey,
            @Path("city") String city);
}
```

And trying to pass the `apikey` and `city` from the `MainActivity` as follows:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        API_Interface weatherService = retrofit.create(API_Interface.class);
        Call<CurrentObservation> call = weatherService.getCurrentWeather(Constants.API_KEY,"Dhaka");

        call.enqueue(new Callback<CurrentObservation>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<CurrentObservation> call, Response<CurrentObservation> response) {
                textView.setText(response.body().toString());
                Log.d("result",response.body().toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<CurrentObservation> call, Throwable t) {
                textView.setText("Something went wrong: " + t.getMessage());
                Log.e("error",t.getMessage());
            }
        });
```

Here is the `Constant` class:

```
public class Constants {
    public static final String BASE_URL="http://api.wunderground.com";
    public static final String API_KEY="b5efba6dc63cc1b1";
}
```

and here is the POJO Model of `CurrentObservation` class: http://paste.ubuntu.com/22291964/
I've overriden a toString() method in the model.

There are some other POJO classes-

### [image]

But this approach gives null response as following-

```
Weather Status: null
Pressure: null
Humidity: null
Temperature: null
```

Here is the actual JSON response from the API URL- http://paste.ubuntu.com/22292683/

How do I pass the parameters into @GET to get the correct response?

Comment: This is correct. Are you sure that `Constants.API_KEY` is correct? What is the HTTP code of the response?

Comment: Added more details..please check now.

Answer (score 1):

Your base URL should look like this:

```
http://blah.com/api/blah/
```

And your `@GET` method should have an URL like this

```
api/{apikey}/conditions/q/BD/{city}.json
```

EDIT: You might have `onResponse` called with an `error body`. Please adjust the following code for your use-case:

```
public static boolean handleError(Retrofit retrofit, Response<?> response) {
    if(response != null && !response.isSuccessful() && response.errorBody() != null) {
        Converter<ResponseBody, ErrorResponse> converter = retrofit.responseBodyConverter(ErrorResponse.class, new Annotation[0]);
        try {
            ErrorResponse errorResponse = converter.convert(response.errorBody());
            // do something
        } catch(IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "An error occurred", e);
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I edited the code as your suggestion now it looks like - public static final String BASE_URL="http://api.wunderground.com/" and @GET("api/{apikey}/conditions/q/BD/{city}.json") but still same result. Null response.

Comment: Ah... well that's odd. Can you try this: `api/{apikey}/conditions/q/BD/{city}` and `Call<CurrentObservation> call = weatherService.getCurrentWeather(Constants.API_KEY,"Dhaka.json");`? Just to eliminate that as a possible cause of the error.

Comment: Tried..still same result :(. I've added some more detail..could you please check one more time?

Comment: okay hold on you might have a success but error body, let me grab the code for testing against that

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like that:

```
@GET
Call<CurrentObservation> getCurrentWeather(@Url String url);
```